# Accessing a Spring Data REST API With Feign

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-hateoas, netflix-feign

I am trying to consume a Rest CRUD API with Feign Client. 
I've added the HATEOAS dependency to the Client application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And here is the Client Interface

```
@FeignClient(name="core-service")
@RibbonClient(name="core-service")
public interface VoteClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/candidates")
    Resources<Candidate> getCandidates();

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/candidates/{id}")
    Resource<Candidate> getCandidate(@PathVariable("id") long id);

}
```

But Here I still have "Candidate cannot be resolved to a Type"
How can I do to read Candidate, which an Entity in the Rest Service, in the Rest Client ?

Comment: Is Candidate.java available somewhere?

Comment: only on the service, not on the Client

Comment: Is this a Java compiler error? If so, the Client needs to have Candidate.java imported.

Comment: Yes when I clicked "fix project setup" and the project where Candidate is defined was imported. Problem fixed! Thank you!

Comment: No problem! I've added a answer just incase someone else runs into this. Please accept it if you can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Java compiler error. The client needs Candidate.java imported on the client. It can be fixed with "Fix Project Setup" on the IDE, or adding the library to the classpath and importing the relevant package.